# How to overload operator >> to vector

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading

```cpp
    #include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// // C++ template to print vector container elements
template <typename T>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const std::vector<T> &v)
{
    os << "[";
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    {
        os << v[i];
        if (i != v.size() - 1)
            os << ", ";
    }
    os << "]\n";
    return os;
}

//Operator overload >> (std::cin)
template <typename T>
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &in, std::vector<T> &v)
{

    for(int i =0;i<v.size();i++)
    {
        in>>v[i];
    }
    return in;
}

//TEST
//  ↓

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec{4, 2, 17, 11, 15};
    std::vector<int> dupa;

    std::cin >> dupa;
    std::cout << vec;

    return 0;
}
```

How can i overload operator >> ??
I don't know how to do it with std :: istream, I get an error "Core Dump (Segmentation fault)" :(
I saw such a task somewhere on the Internet and I wanted to do it, but there is no solution. I don't want to use "v.push_back (..)"

Comment: You don't, you use `std::istream_iterator` and one of `back_inserter` or friends. Also, you do not understand how `std::vector` works at all.

Comment: cannot reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/xxqaGY. You are not reading anything to `dupa` because you only read into already existing elements, but otherwise looks ok

Comment: Your input function is incompatible with the output function.  The output function uses commas to separate the numbers.  One would expect that you could call the output function to a file, rewind the file, then use the input function, *without having to change the process*.

Comment: You are reading in a `vector` from `std::cin`.  What format are you expecting the user to type in the values as? Your `operator>>` is expecting the `vector` to have already been pre-sized, but it is not, since you don't know how many values the user is actually entering. What format do you WANT the user to type in? That is the format you need to code your `operator>>` to handle. Your `operator<<` is using the format `"[value, value, ....]\n"`, you can certainly require the user to use a similar format, if you want to. Though maybe something like `"# value value ..."` would be easier to handle.

Comment: @RolandasUlevicius the code shown will not work as-is. In `std::vector<int> dupa; std::cin >> dupa;`, the `operator>>` tries to read `dupa.size()` number of integers, but `size()` is 0, so nothing is read from `std::cin` at all.

Comment: chaos happened, I would like to know how the overload of this operator should look like because I don't know anything

Answer (score 2):

When you initially define a `std::vector`, then it has 0 elements. It is empty. So, you cannot access any element, also not the first element, which would be for example "vec[0]". This will typically result in a "Segmentation fault".

So, either you must use one of the functions that add either add elements to the vector or, you must resize you empty `std::vector` to a given size. Then you can access the existing elements.

Your input loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
```

will not be executed, because the size is 0.

The usage "add element" functions would be recommended. Like `push_back` or `insert` or `emplace_back` or convienience wrappers like `back_inserter` or whatever.

But before reading data into a `std::vector` element, it must exist. Or, you read into a temp variable and then use some of the above mentioned functions.

Unfortunately there is no other way

Comment: If you want to answer to the commenters, consider doing that in the comments. Doing that in the answer is distracting, and the people you're addressing won't even get notifications.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I will try to improve myself. And thank you for deleting parts of my answer